# Change entity status depending on datetime value

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, hexagonal-architecture

I have a `Subscription` entity that has `status` and `canceledAt` fields.

I want `status` to change from `active` to `canceled` when `canceledAt` has expired.

So, I imagine checking canceledAt in `Subscription::getStatus` method:

```
// Subscription.php

public function getStatus()
{
     // .... check canceledAt

     return $this->status;
}
```

but that would also require to change the status at **persistence** layer.

Should I do something with events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I created an application service to get the status of a subscription so I can store it in the database in case it is needed.

Moreover, I removed the `getStatus` method from `Subscription` entity.

Answer (score 0):

> If you don't consider time an input value, think about it until you do - it is an important concept -- [John Carmack, 1998](https://github.com/ESWAT/john-carmack-plan-archive/blob/master/by_year/johnc_plan_1998.txt)

For a simple query, a straight forward way to handle this is to pass the current time as an input

```
// Subscription.php

public function getStatus(currentTime)
{
    // .... check canceledAt
    if (currentTime > canceledAt) {
        // ....
    }

    return $this->status;
}
```

On the other hand, if what you are trying to do is effect an authoritative change in status, then you pass the current time to you domain model in a *command*.

```
public function onTick(currentTime) {
    // ....
}
```

In some cases, it may make sense to represent time via a domain service representation of a clock, rather than as a value.  The important point is that the application, not the domain model, is responsible for "what time is it?"

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't persist any status. Just the canceledAt datetime. Why? Because the status depends on current datetime. You could persist a status value now, but that value could be wrong e.g. the next minute. Then, from the next minute and later, you would have a wrong value persisted.

In my opinion, it doesn't make sense to persist a value that changes depending on time, because the meaning of persist is right the opposite, is to store a value that won't change per se.

I would calculate the status when requested, depending on current datetime and canceledAt, but I wouldn't persist it. Since it depends on current datetime you should consider current datetime as an input value, like @VoiceOfUnreason said in his answer.